# How to add small changes to the default behavior of spring-boot-starter-data-rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` dependency in my project which really saves a lot of time and automatically creates Rest endpoints for the entities that have an associated `CrudRepository` repository defined in the project. But let's say one of my entity is `Article` and authenticated users (Session authentication in this example) can create articles from the POST endpoint. In my `Article` table I have one column `user_id` and it represents the id of the user who created the article.

Now the user can use POST endpoint and send the `user_id` property which is not really secure, one user could set this id and pretend another user posted one article. So I have to set this property on the back-end level (from the session informations of the user).

I am a bit new to the spring environment and now the only solution i can think of is to rewrite the endpoint entirely so I can store `user_id` properly into the database. This is counter-productive because this is a very tiny change to the default behavior `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` provides. Isn't there a solution where I can catch the Article object before it is pushed into the database so I can just set `user_id` and send it back to the default processing ?

Answer (score 0):

Off course, you can use jpa entityListeners where you can use the @preUpdate and @prePersist annotations

https://www.concretepage.com/java/jpa/jpa-entitylisteners-example-with-callbacks-prepersist-postpersist-postload-preupdate-postupdate-preremove-postremove